# Is it possible to trace back words to its original doc in doc2vec?

Tags: python, word2vec, doc2vec

I would love to make a doc2vec/word2vec dataset that is able to traceback or remember its original placement. For now I would love to know in which row or txt file it came from but in the future even its original paragraph. For example, I would love to be able to do it with multiple txt files or an csv.

Searching for similar codes or ideas like these did not do any justice. So I’m curious if someone else knows how or if it even would be even possible at all to; **embed or let the words remember its original location(document).**

**Example Input:**

```
        Author    |   Title   |     d2v_text     
———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————                  
0          Name 1 |  Title 1  | this is the first text. first text paragraph.    
1          Name 2 |  Title 2  | this is the second text. second text paragraph.
2          Name 3 |  Title 3  | this is the thirth text. thirth text paragraph.

Name1Title1.txt  (this is the first text. first text paragraph) 
Name2Title2.txt  (this is the second text. second text paragraph)
Name3Title3.txt  (this is the thirth text. thirth text paragraph)
```

**Example output:**

```
(‘second’, 0.2384900293, ‘Name2Title2’)
(‘text’,0.34948302,’Name1Title1,Name2Title2,Name3Title3’) 

w1 = [“text”]
model.wv.most_similar (positive=w1,topn=1)

[(‘second’, 0.2384900293, ‘Name2Title2’)]
```

What I would like to achieve is that, when loading and printing a certain vector from a dataset that it would know its original document. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: No. You lose this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These models don't store their training data – they just observe it during each of the training passes, to build their vector-models for each word or doc.

For `Doc2Vec` doc-vectors, it's traditional to name the doc-vector with some unique key to the original document, such as an ID-number or filename. So for doc-vectors, the tag reported with results probably already provides the key you need.

For words, when you want a list of all documents a word appears in, the two traditional approaches are:

- brute-force scan, as with the command-line program `grep`, where you look over every word in every document and return the list of documents where the word appeared. For example, if you had a directory with your `Name1Title1.txt` etc files, the command `grep -l -E '(^|\W)second(\W|$)' *.txt` would print those files containing the word `second`. Of course, this is very slow over a large corpus.
- building an *[inverted index](https://en.wivipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index)* of which documents contain which words. Then, after the cost of one scan and building/storing the index, finding the list of docs for any word is very quick. This is the foundational technique enabling full-text search engines.

A simple inverted index takes just a few lines of Python:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
docs = (  # tuples of doc-name, words
    ('Name1Title1.txt', "this is the first text. first text paragraph".split()),
    ('Name2Title2.txt', "this is the second text. second text paragraph".split()),
    ('Name3Title3.txt', "this is the thirth text. thirth text paragraph".split()),
)
inv_index = defaultdict(list)
for title, words in docs:
    for word in set(words):
        inv_index[word].append(title)
```

Then, the list of any docs where a word appeared is a simple lookup:

```py
>>> inv_index['second']
['Name2Title2.txt']
>>> inv_index['this']
['Name1Title1.txt', 'Name2Title2.txt', 'Name3Title3.txt']
```

Inverted indexes can be quite large, and so often use other datastructures for compactness, including file-based indexes – so if your corpus is large, you may need to research other libraries for inverted-indexing to be able to build your index and do your lookups in a practical way.